# Click event only called once and button is not reenable

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, onclick, dom-events

The following Javascript code only calls the click handler at the first click and does not reenable the button:

```
var shareSection = $("#share");    
var shortenButton = $('#shorten'); //No it is not jQuery. It is simply a predefined shortcut for querySelector
shortenButton.onclick = function() {
    shortenButton.disabled = true;
    if (isShortened)
    {
        shareSection.innerHTML = shareSection.innerHTML.replaceAll(shortened, expanded);
        isShortened = false;
        toggleShortenButton(shortenButton, isShortened);
        shortenButton.disabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!shortened)
        {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (request.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                    if (request.status == 200)
                    {
                        shortened = request.responseText;
                        shareSection.innerHTML = shareSection.innerHTML.replaceAll(expanded, shortened);
                        isShortened = true;
                        toggleShortenButton(shortenButton, isShortened);
                        shortenButton.disabled = false;
                    }
                }
            };
            request.open("get", window.location.href + "shorten/", true);
            request.send();    
        }
        else
        {
            shareSection.innerHTML = shareSection.innerHTML.replaceAll(expanded, shortened);
            isShortened = true;
            toggleShortenButton(shortenButton, isShortened);
            shortenButton.disabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And the handler is not called again because the button is disabled, even if I remove `shortenButton.disabled = true;` it is only called on the first click.
The rendered html looks like this:

```
<section id="share"> 
    <ul class="share">
        <li><label>Share:<input type="text" value="http://easypolls.herokuapp.com/1/" readonly /></label></li>
        <li><label>Embed:<input type="text" value="<iframe src=&quot;http://easypolls.herokuapp.com/1/&quot;></iframe>" readonly /></label>
    </ul>
    <ul class="share">
        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://easypolls.herokuapp.com/1/&t=Is%20this%20site%20great%3F" target="_blank" title="Share on Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="sr-only">Share on Facebook</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?&url=http://easypolls.herokuapp.com/1/&text=Is%20this%20site%20great%3F" target="_blank" title="Tweet"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="sr-only">Tweet</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://easypolls.herokuapp.com/1/" target="_blank" title="Share on Google+"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="sr-only">Share on Google+</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="button" id="shorten" value="Shorten links" />    
</section>
```

Comment: The first time the button is clicked the event is fired correctly.

Comment: No it is not jQuery. It is simpy a predefined shortcut for `querySelector`.

Comment: Share your HTML, as you are manipulating HTML, is `shortenButton` child of `shareSection`

Comment: I included the html.

Comment: does `shareSection = $('#share')`?

Comment: Yes that expression is used to select the section.

Comment: Then issue will exists as you are replacing its content, notice `shareSection.innerHTML = shareSection.innerHTML.replaceAll(....`  Change your logic instead of using `replaceAll()`